# Sails.js find records and store result into a var

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, sails.js

I want to query MongoDb, and save the returned records into a variable, Here is what I tried in my Controller :

```
var projects= {};

Project.find({}).exec(function findProject(err, found){

       projects = found;
       console.log(found.length);

       while (found.length)
         console.log('Found Project with name ' + found.pop().name)
});
```

// This returns Undefined

```
console.log(projects.length);
```

Am I doing it wrong ?

How can I pass result of .find() into the variable projects ?

Answer (score 2):

You should stop **pop()** -ing your array.
Your object is being passed *[by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)*, and not *[by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value)*. So when you delete items from one you actually influence the other.

**Edit:**

If you still have doubts, you can examine your query:

```
Project.find({}).exec(function findProject(err, found){
     if (err) { // here
          console.log(err);
     } else if (found.length == 0){
          console.log("Nothing was found");
     } else {
          console.log(found);
     }
});
```

Objects don't have a `.length` property, and that's why you get `undefined`. I assume you get an error, and that's why your `found` parameter is not an array.

Comment: What doesn't work is this `projects = found;` it's undefined.How can I pass result of .find() into the variable projects ?

Comment: @Grimmy, sorry for the delay. Please refer to my edit.